# numpy searchsorted with side='right' on numpy.arange, giving incorrect result

Tags: python, numpy

In below code I am trying to get index of number 14 from ***`right`*** side using `searchsorted` function in numpy.

I have created the array to be searched using `np.arange` function.

**Actual output is**

> [ 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48]
> Index of 14 is :  **`7`**
> Element at 7 is :  16

**Expected output is**

> [ 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48]
> Index of 14 is :  **`17`**
> Element at 7 is :  14

Could you explain

- if my understanding is correct, that the result of `np.searchsorted` should be 17 , and
- why I am not getting index 7, when I have put the `side = 'right'`

I was referring example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_numpy_array_search5)

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(2,50,2)
print(arr)

x = np.searchsorted(arr, 14, side='right')

print('Index of 14 is : ',x)
print("Element at "+str(x)+" is : ",arr[x])
```

Comment: If you want to insert to the right side of 14, you have to insert at index 7, ie `2 4 6 8 10 12 14 {here} 16`

Comment: Thanks @zvone, I went through the docs again, it makes sense now